Синхронизация времени Астра линукса у Windows
Надо синхронизирывать время Астры(линукс) у Виндовс сервера он же проксик. Произошла такая ситуация надо синхронизирывать время линукса у винды в локальной сети!
Базово есть Астра и прокси сервер 192.168.111.222 с которым с которым мне нужно синхронизирываться. в интернете полно информации о том как настроить в timedatectl часовой пояс, но нет информации как синхронизирыватся с другим компьютером, особено на котором винда.
В Винде все проста w32tm, она может синхронизирыватся с любым компом в локальной сети. Возможно ли так сделать в Линуксе, точнее в Астре? Подскажите как можно синхранизирывать время рабочей станции под Астра линукс с прокси сервером под Windows. Желательно с использованием терминала и возможностью написаний скрипта.
В сети стоит http аунтификация через прокси сервер и проста синхронизирыватся в интернете не получится. Так же решением может быть как приучить синхронизирыватся через прокси сервер с аунтификацией. В идеале все же синхронизация времени с прокси сервером.

Ну поднимите на Windows любой NTP сервер (а хоть бы и штатный), и указывайте его в качестве источника времени линям. Файрвол только настроить не забудьте...

Поднимите в windows сервер ntp и синхронизируйте с ним через ntpclient

Испробывал все что возможно и такой вывод
`administrator@icm01906:~$ sudo ntpdate 192.168.221.111
[sudo] пароль для administrator:
11 Nov 11:03:28 ntpdate[9285]: no server suitable for synchronization found
administrator@icm01906:~$
`
На проксе по словам администратора поднят w32tm, как я понимаю это разногласия ОС
